# Circular dependency error for any service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

I'm getting a circular dependency error (only in the browser, not from the angular compiler) for **any** of my own services that I try to use in my route guard functions.

The **router configuration** is very basic:

`app-routing.module.ts`

```
import { ExtraOptions, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { inject, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
  NbAuthComponent,
} from '@nebular/auth';
import { NbAuthService } from './authentication/services/auth.service';
import { RoutePermissionsGuard } from './services/routePermissions.guard';

/* import { NgxAuthModule } from './pages/auth/auth.module'; */

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pages',
    /* canActivate: [() => inject(NbAuthService).isAuthenticatedOrRefresh()], */
    canActivate: [RoutePermissionsGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module')
      .then(m => m.PagesModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'token',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module')
      .then(m => m.PagesModule),
  },
    {   
    path: 'auth',
    component: NbAuthComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./authentication/auth.module').then(m => m.NbAuthModule),
 
  }  ,
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'foo/bar', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: false,
   enableTracing: true 
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

No matter if I do it Angular 15 style with direct injection like

```
canActivate: [() => inject(NbAuthService).isAuthenticatedOrRefresh()]
```

or create a Class like

```
@Injectable()
export class RoutePermissionsGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private api: ApiService,  private auth: NbAuthService, private router: Router, private tokenService: NbTokenService ) {}
```

Using any of the services I've built will throw the `Circular dependency in DI detected for Foo` error, the compiler shows nothing though.

How can I debug this?

Comment: What is the full exception? Can you provide implementations for NgAuthService and NbTokenService and how its added to the injector? Is it via root?

Comment: Hey, here is the repo, NgAuthService and NbTokenService are added here if i understand correctly: https://github.com/nikita-fuchs/med_poc_frontend/blob/stack_overflow/src/app/authentication/auth.module.ts#L132 and here it's used in a routing guard: https://github.com/nikita-fuchs/med_poc_frontend/blob/stack_overflow/src/app/app-routing.module.ts#L20 The full exception is https://pastebin.com/6g10hTd0 - reproduce by `ng serve`and visit `/pages/`.
 I'd tip you a little for any help, my discord is n1cK#4197 - thank you very much !